# Can I use different server IP address in NTP time synchronization?

Tags: linux, centos, ntp

By default, it is something like,

```
server 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org
server 1.rhel.pool.ntp.org
server 2.rhel.pool.ntp.org
```

Can I choose my server IP address for synchronizing time?

Comment: Check `/etc/ntp.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

You can also query to which server(s) you are talking by `ntpq -p`.

Here you will find [official documentation for NTP](http://www.ntp.org/documentation.html).

Answer (score 0):

NTP allows to sync your computer time from the internet.

the **server** line defines from which server the time will be queried.

Yes this is configurable and 2-4 timeservers are recommended to be configured.

My personal recommendation is to use [0-4].< country or continent >.pool.ntp.org for servers as these are mostly supposed to be geographically and networwise closer to you. They are expected to be a bit better for you. My personal config is:

> server clock.local prefer
>   server 1.europe.pool.ntp.org iburst
>   server 2.europe.pool.ntp.org iburst
>   server 3.europe.pool.ntp.org iburst

Which translates to:

- Use clock.local if available and all other params (e.g. jitter) are equal
- yes we have a gps we use for clock source in the office (but not at home)
- use all 4 to get a good time
- use fast sync algorithm for the eu ones
- use europe based servers (i am in eu)

If your question is can the NTP requests to the servers originate from a specific IP address available on your machine then you are looking for the option **interface**

```
   interface [listen | ignore | drop] [all | ipv4 | ipv6 | wildcard | name | address[/prefixlen]]
          This command controls which network addresses ntpd opens, and whether input is dropped without processing.
```

Comment: Why not just use iburst for the local clock to?

Comment: it is expected to be always available and responding properly. If not do the full cycle. There is no issue using iburst on it, just a preference.

Comment: I do not understand what "do the full cycle" means. And why would you have a preference for delaying the sync to your preferred host?